# One managed package not included in Enterprise wsdl , Unable to access managed package object from java using SOAP API

Tags: apex, managed-package, integration, enterprise-wsdl

I am using SOAP API(enterprise WSDL) to acess the salesforce from java. My salesforce org has a  few managed packages(around 10).

I am able to access the custom objects and managed package objects via java,. However i am unable to accees an object(ksfdc_product) from one managed package. While debugging in to wsdl i found that salesforce had not included this package(namespace: ksfdc) while creating enterprise wsdl.

Also salesforce is not listing few packages in package version settings page while creating enterprise wsdl.

Could anyone let me know the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The enterprise WSDL is strongly-typed and tailored to your org. From the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm):

> The generated WSDL defines all of the API calls, objects (including
>   standard and custom objects), and fields that are available for API
>   access for your organization.

My guess is that either of this two things could be the reason for your issue:

- You created the WSDL and then installed 1 or more package(s)
- The objects in the package are not available for API access.

Maybe recreating the WSDL could solve your issue.

If that does not fix your issue, as a workaround, you could use the Partner WSDL, which is loosely-typed, and you could reference your object and fields by name. for more information on the difference between both, see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004760&language=en_US).

Answer (score 0):

You Can try the given Steps:

User who is generating enterprise WSDL, should have:

1) License assigned under -> Installed Packages -> Choose your package -> Click on "Manage Licenses" on Package Details page.

2) All required permission on Managed Package like Read, Write, Edit

Also try to Select the Lowest version of Managed Package while generating Enterprise WSDL from Salesforce Setup-> API -> Generate Enterprise WSDL

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_wsdl_enterprise_version.htm